# Can't set appPool in windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, wix

I have a MSI file we wrote.
The installation is a WIX installation and it calls a customAction

```
 <CustomAction Id="Allow32" FileKey="myProgram.exe" ExeCommand="Allow32" Return="ignore" Execute="deferred" />
```

The customAction does the following (C#):

```
string res = Utils.RunProcess(Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("systemroot"), "system32\\inetsrv\\appcmd.exe"), "set apppool \"Classic .NET AppPool\"  -enable32BitAppOnWin64:true");
```

When I try to install the MSI on windows 8 / Server 2012 R2 - it fails.
On windowx XP and Windows 7 it works fine.

Also when I use "Administrator" user it works fine but I can't rely on that because I need to install the MSI on customer computers and I don't have an access to their Administrator user.

Comment: Do you have any install logs or further information *why* it fails on Windows 8 and Server 2012 R2? Do you have a specific error message, can you tell where the error message originates?

Comment: are you trying to write to a secure location in windows 8 ?  if you are writing to IIS folders it locks them down and you need admin access to write to them, this can be changed by setting the ownership settings for the user although this decreases the security of the system. you could also try publishing it as x64 as that solves some issues with windows 8 / server 2012

Comment: @stakx - in the installation log I get this row:
CustomAction Allow32 returned actual error code -532459699 but will be translated to success due to continue marking